# Xcode - Segue - Pass Variable From Cell class to TableViewController class

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, segue

I'm struggling to pass a variable from one class to another. I've done some reading and the Segue method seems the most appropriate for me, I just can't get it to work. A little help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a `UITableView` (`TableViewController1`), which contains a cell (`Cell1`), which contains a label (`ReferenceLabel 1`). `Table 1` is populated from an array; each cell contains a reference number (contained within `ReferenceLabelLabel 1`). The reference number from the selected cell needs to be passed to `TableViewController2`.

What I have so far:

`TableViewController1.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h> 
#define kGETUrl @"http://localhost/RC.php"
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {    
NSMutableArray *json;    
}
@end
```

`TableViewController1.m`

```
#import "TableViewController1.h"
#import "TableViewController2.h"
#import "TableViewCell1.h"

@interface TableViewController1 ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController1

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style {

    self = [super initWithStyle:style];

    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) getData:(NSData *) data {

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void) start {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrl];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [self getData:data];

}

#pragma mark - View Lifecycle
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [self start];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {


    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [json count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell1";

 TableViewCell1 *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

 if (cell == nil) {
 cell = [[TableViewCell1 alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }
 NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.ReferenceLabel1.text = [info objectForKey:@"id"];

    return cell;
 }

//I'm stuck with the following... any help appreciate... i cant figure how to send the selected row's ReferenceLabel.text value
    -(void)TableViewController1:(UITableView *)TableViewController1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TVC1RefNumberTVC2" sender:self];
    }


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"TVC1RefNumberTVC2"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *ip = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
                      DetailObject *detail = [self detailForIndexPath:path];
        [segue.destinationViewController setDetail:detail];
    }
}

@end
```

As for `TableViewController2`, I'm guessing I simply need to create a property for the variable I'm sending from `TableViewController1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that you need to declare a property in your second view controller so that you can access it from your first view controller's prepareForSegue method.

You can declare a property in TableViewController2's header file that looks something like this:
`@property (nonatomic, strong) DetailObject *detail;`

And then set its detail property within the if clause within your TableViewController1's prepareForSegue method like this:

`TableViewController2 *tableViewController2 = segue.destinationViewController
tableViewController2.detail = detail;`

You can also add an additional check before casting the segue.destinationViewController by checking if the destinationVC's class matches that of TableViewController2.